# Max Pixels error in Monthly NDVI values

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap

I'm trying to find monthly NDVI using Landsat but I'm facing max pixel error in my chart. when I use it to small geometry then code works fine for monthly NDVI but gives max pixels error for larger geometry. Also I want to know if this is fine way or not for monthly NDVI. My code is:

```
//////////////////Landsat NDVI Map and Chart/////////////////////////

var l8_collection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA")
.filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-06-30')
.filterMetadata ('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 20)
.filterBounds(geometry);

var addNDVI = function(image) {
return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']));
};

var l8 = l8_collection.map(addNDVI)
var NDVI = l8.select(['nd']);
var NDVImed = NDVI.median(); 
var ndviVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};
// Map.addLayer(NDVImed.clip(geometry),ndviVis, 'Landsat NDVI');


//////////Daily NDVI chart
var plotNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(l8, geometry,ee.Reducer.mean(),'nd',30,'system:time_start', 'system:index')
              .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
                title: 'Landsat NDVI short-term time series',
                hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
                vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'}
});
// print(plotNDVI);


/////////Montly NDVI chart

print(Chart.image.series(l8.select('nd'), geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(),30)
.setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
                title: 'Landsat NDVI short-term time series',
                hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
                vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
                maxPixels: 1e16,
}))
```

Script for geometry is: https://code.earthengine.google.com/38389a07616e2bd927cc9a2431a345f1

Answer (score 0):

Those chart helper functions don't have a maxPixels option.  You'll need to use a slightly larger scale to fit in under the maxPixels limit.  (60 works)